# xml error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object after SelectSingleNode

Tags: c#, .net, xml

here's my code:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
foreach (string c in colorList)
{
     doc.Load(@"http://whoisxmlapi.com/whoisserver/WhoisService?domainName=" + c + @"&username=user&password=pass");
     textBox1.Text += doc.SelectSingleNode("WhoisRecord/registrant/email").InnerText + ",";
}
```

for the second line of code (textbox1...) is generating this error
what am i doing wrong?

Comment: **Show us a sample XML** so we can see what might be happening! Your XPath could be wrong (selecting nothing), possibly because of lack of respect for an XML namespace - or there are lots of other reasons - but without the XML, we can't possibly tell just from your code......

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about splitting up the line to see where the exception occurs?

```
// if node is null the problem is with SelectSingleNode 
XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("WhoisRecord/registrant/email");

// if text is null the problem is with the node 
string text = node.InnerText;

// if textBox1 is null the problem is with textBox1
textBox1.Text += text + ",";
```

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation for SelectSingleNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb63z0tw.aspx) states it returns null if no matching node is found. You'll have to fix the query or handle a failure to find a match.

Comment: I bet you didn't paste the SelectSingleNode call into your browser, since that's the thing that's failing. The capitalization in your XPath looks suspicious, you sure it's correct?

Comment: Besides... what did you paste for the "c" variable used?

The XPath is missing an element (registryData) between 'WhoisRecord' and 'registrant'. I also noticed when you select a domain that is 'available' the registrant element will be empty and therefore cause the mentioned 'Null' reference exception.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason you would get a `NullReferenceException` is if the XPath query is returning null. Examine the XML before running the query to see what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

it appears that `doc.SelectSingleNode("WhoisRecord/registrant/email")` is null. Can't get property of a null.

Comment: you can debug, decompose the code, make variables for each intermediary value, check if their value corresponds to what you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers do all sorts of other clever stuff like following redirects and dealing with sessions. How about stepping into the code and having a look at the XmlDocument's OuterXml property for the document that fails?